# Avoiding arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF locking mxd with data driven pages?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, data-driven-pages, mxd

I've written a script that makes use of a data driven pages mxd, but I'm having issues with locks. The script iterates through a series of feature classes and uses them as the base layer for the DDP. I've found that once an mxd object is created, saved, and the code `arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF` is used, the mxd can't be saved again. The code `mxd.save ()` fails on its second iteration. I've run the script commenting out `arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF` and the script ran fine. Here's my code:

```
oldMapDoc = mapDoc

#iterate feature classes
for i, fc in enumerate (sorted (fcs)):
    print fc
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument (mapDoc)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    ddpLyr = [l for l in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers (mxd) if l.name == "Symbology"] [0]
    ddpLyr.replaceDataSource (platsGdb, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", fc)
    mapFolder = os.path.join (distFolder, fc.title ().replace ("_", " "))
    mxd.save ()
    pageCount =  mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount
    print pageCount
    for pageNum in range(1, pageCount + 1):
        mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
        index = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageNameField.name
        plat = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.getValue (index).replace ("\\", "_")
        outPdfName = fc + "_" + plat + ".pdf"
        pageId = mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID
        print "Exporting page {} of {}: {}".format(pageId,
                                                   pageCount,
                                                   outPdfName)
        outPdf = os.path.join (mapFolder, outPdfName)
        if arcpy.Exists (outPdf):
            print "already made"
            continue
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF (mxd, outPdf)
        #break
    del mxd, df, ddpLyr, index, plat, outPdfName, pageId, mapFolder, pageCount
    mapDoc = oldMapDoc.replace (".mxd", "") + "_" + str (i) + ".mxd"
    print "copying"
    copyfile (oldMapDoc, mapDoc)
```

I've tried the variation of creating the mxd object outside of the loop. This produces a different error - the script runs but the DDP layer never actually updates.

As you can see, I've created a workaround where I copy the mxd file with each iteration. It works, but it's pretty wonky. Has anyone dealt with this issue before and found a solution besides something hokey like I have?

Comment: Why do you need to save the same mxd on each iteration?  Does export to PDF require a save first?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?  10.3 has a bug with DDP which is resolved in 10.4.  This may be part of your problem.

Comment: under your line mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument (mapDoc) add the line ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages then export to pdf using ddp.exportToPDF("name_of_your_pdf", "ALL")

Comment: If I don't save the `mxd` the line of code `pageCount =  mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount` seems to fail. The count remains the same as it iterates through each feature class, until it hits a feature class with less than the given count of pages. Then I get an index out of range sort of error when it tries to find a page that doesn't exist. I'm using 10.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I frequently write applications that automate export to PDF from an index layer by simply using a SearchCursor to "visit" each feature extent, do any desired manipulations, and then export to PDF without saving the MXD.

I find this much easier and more flexible to do than trying to merge Data Driven Pages functions with ArcPy code.